# Update same table with IF ELSE Condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update the `user_status` filed with condition:

```
update pm_users 
    set user_status = if ( 
      (select u.user_status from pm_users u where u.user_id = 3
      ) = '1', '0', '1' )
    where user_id = 3
```

means if `user_status = 1` then update the status with 0 and if user status is 0 then with 1.

I am getting the error: `You can't specify target table 'pm_users' for update in FROM clause`

I think it means i can't use this query like above for the same table? I am not sure.
Please help me to move on the right way, and make me correct.

Comment: Are you meant to update the status of user_id = 3 based on the status of user_id = 2?

Comment: @astander sorry for the little typo mistake, both the user id is same, i have updated my question.

Comment: As far as the user_id condition is same you can try `Case When user_status = 0 Then 1 else 0 end`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try the following

```
update pm_users 
    set user_status = case when user_status = 0 then 1 else 0 end
    where user_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then maybe try [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

```
update pm_users 
    set user_status = CASE WHEN user_status = '1' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
WHERE user_id = 3
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50cc92/1)

Comment: OHH, you mean i don't have to user `select` query for the same table